# Change company name in GitLab E-Mails

Tags: gitlab

I have a fresh installation of GitLab 15.7.2. When a new user is created, it sends a notification E-Mail via SMTP to that user, saying `The Administrator created an account for you. Now you are a member of the company GitLab application.`
How can I change the company name `GitLab application` ?

Answer (score 1):

After a little research, I realized that we cannot change Gitlab's email notifications.
In addition, this sentence does not mean the name of your company, it just says that you have been added to your company's Gatilab